# How to push int/float variadic arguments into vector<double>?

Tags: c++

```
class Entity
{
private:
    std::vector<double> m_Numbers;
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    Entity(Args... parameters)
        : m_Numbers{ parameters... } {}
};

int main()
{
    Entity e1(5, 7);
}
```

Unexpectedly, the vector did not convert the `int`s into `double`s and threw out an error:

> C2398 | Element '0': conversion from 'int' to '_Ty' requires a narrowing conversion`

Is there a way to have `std::vector<double>` accept any number type (e.g. `int`/`float`/`uint32_t`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform an explicit conversion to `double`.

```
    : m_Numbers{static_cast<double>(parameters)... } {}
```

The problem is that `std::vector`'s constructor requires `double`s since that's the type it stores.  Since you're constructing with brace initialization, implicit conversions aren't allowed, hence your warning (although with gcc I only get a warning).

Comment: Unfortunately it threw out another error: 'std::foward': none of the 2 overloads could convert all argument types. But it led me to using static_cast<double>, which worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that error, but `static_cast` is actually a better solution than `std::forward`.  Updating my answer to reflect that.  Actually, I'm embarrassed I didn't see it right away.

Comment: Implicit conversions are allowed, just not *narrowing conversions*. Although it is not really clear to me why initializing a double with an int is considered "narrowing"

Comment: @M.M Essentially all conversions that might not give the same value after round-trip conversion are considered narrowing. So if the initializer used is not a constant expression all conversions between integers and floating points are forbidden.

Comment: A minor clarification: "I only get a warning" conforms to the language definition. The standard requires that a compiler "issue a diagnostic" for ill-formed code. Having done that, it's free to do anything, including continuing to compile the code with an implementation-specific meaning. Here, the meaning is almost certainly that it applies the appropriate conversion. More specifically: the standard does not require that the compiler refuse to compile the code.

Comment: @M.M -- for a sufficiently large integer type, there are values that cannot be represented exactly in a `double`. Loosely speaking, if the number of bits in the integer type exceeds the number of bits in the mantissa of the `double`, large integer values can't be represented exactly; they'll lose a few bits off the low end.

Comment: @PeteBecker but if the type is one where all values can be exactly represented on the system?

Comment: @M.M -- if the type being converted to can represent all possible values of the type being converted there is no narrowing. That's not the case with large-sized integers being converted to floating-point values. We think of floating-point types as having a large range, which they do, but they do that at the cost of precision, and it's the loss of precision that makes it a narrowing conversion.

Comment: @M.M -- for example, an IEEE double (64 bits, with a 53 bit mantissa) can represent all values of an 8-bit `char` exactly, so when converting `char` to `double` there would be no narrowing; it cannot represent all values of a 64-bit `long long` (since it only has 53 bits for the digits), so converting `long long` to `double` would be a narrowing conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker `char` to `double` is considered a narrowing conversion by the standard though. (and rejected by the compiler)

Comment: @M.M -- wow. I haven't looked at this stuff, and just assumed it would be rational. :-(

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah same... walnut's comment seems like a reasonable explanation and I guess they didn't want the same code to report "error - narrowing" on some systems but pass OK on others, depending on sizeof(int)

Comment: @M.M -- yup, **any** integer type to any floating-point type is a narrowing conversion. (With the universal exception that a constant that fits is okay).

Answer (score 1):

With brace initialization, implicit conversions aren't allowed, but you can use `push_back` and the parameter pack expansion, as follows.

```
class Entity
{
private:
    std::vector<double> m_Numbers;
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    Entity(T first, Args... parameters){
        (m_Numbers.push_back(parameters),...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Using `: m_CurrentNumbers{ static_cast<double>(parameters)... } {}` worked to explicitly convert all the arguments into double.